# Confusion in asking a htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess

I was tryig to learn .htaccess, and and had a question regarding this, i have asked the question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26421/htaccess-issue-500-internal-server-error-error)
Have I correctly pasted the question on pro webmaster or I should do it here on stackoverflow?

sorry, but i am much confused as **htaccess** tag is present at both locations. Sorry again if i have broke some rule

Comment: better on webmasters or serverfault.

Comment: but there are a very few people following the tag (as compared to stackoverflow), Should this duplication of tags be resolved (if is it duplication)?

Comment: I would disagree, since you are clearly not a webmaster or server administrator.  But looking at your .htaccess, you've got the 500 because the syntax is wrong. It should be `$1.php`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a meta issue and might be better asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the 500 because the syntax is wrong. It should be `$1.php`.  $a is not a valid variable.

I've moved this to an answer, so you can mark it as resolved.

Comment: i have tried '$1.php' but still the problem exists

Comment: If you want use to tell you why your getting a 500, then you have to edit your Q to add your full `.htaccess`.  I am not clairvoyant.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on your PHP scripts and their parent directories?  If your host is running suPHP or suEXEC, then the scripts should be `-rw--r--r` or `-rw------`, the static files read by apache `-rw--r---r--`, and the directories owned by you should be `drwx--x--x` or `drwxr-xr-x` if you don't mind public read access.  You will need to allow `o:x` so that apache can read the static files and `.htaccess` files that they contain.